# Oracle: unable to fetch the record based on latest record inserted and join with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g, left-join

I have a tables as below:

```
USERS

 USERID             EMAIL
 ----------------------
 1              xxx@xxx.com
 2              yyy@yyy.com

AUDIT_ITEM
 AI_ID          AI_NAME
----------------------------
   1            AAA
   2            BBB
   3            CCC
   4            DDD

AUDIT_LOG
AL_ID       USERID      AI_ID   PACKAGING_ID        INSERT_DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1           2           1           100             09/09/2014
2           1           2           102             09/09/2014
3           1           3           103             09/09/2014
4           1           1           100             09/09/2014 ( LATEST RECORD INSERTED)
```

Now I want the user email based on the latest record inserted in AUDIT_LOG table(in this case it's xxx@xxx.com) where AI_NAME='AAA' and PACKAGING_ID = 100. Note the the INSERT_DATE is of DATE type

Comment: What's your criteria for "last record inserted"? It it's the `INSERT_DATE`, then there is no difference in the four records you've shown. If it is greatest `AL_ID`, then you should say that.

Comment: yes its INSERT_DATE which has to decide which record is latest

Comment: But the `INSERT_DATE` is the same on all four records, so how do you know which one is the latest?

Comment: The insert_date is of type DATE, in oracle it shows us just the date but actually it also has the time, so we have to identify the based on considering the timestamp as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the `with` clause to limit the log entries to those of packaging_id 100 and ai_name AAA. Then it simply becomes:

```
with logs as
       (select l.*
          from audit_log l join audit_item i on l.ai_id = i.ai_id
         where l.packaging_id = 100 and i.ai_name = 'AAA')
select u.email
  from users u join logs l on u.userid = l.userid
 where l.insert_date = (select max(insert_date) from logs);
```

Comment: this wont work as you have not considered  AI_NAME='AAA' , I want only for AI_ID=1 in query we should check for like where audit_log.AI_ID=audit_item.AI_ID and audit_item.NAME='AAA'

Comment: Updated to include the item criteria.

Comment: thank for all you support but am confused on where to put PACKAGING_ID = 100 in the query as I want it for packging_id 100 only

Comment: Just add it to the `where` clause, as I've done in my last edit.

Comment: this query is not giving any result, if you remove the date check then it will return two records with email as xxx@xxx.com & yyy@yyy.com but I only need one xxx@xxx.com which is of the latest

Comment: this query is not giving any result, if you remove the date check then it will return two records with email as xxx@xxx.com & yyy@yyy.com but I only need one xxx@xxx.com which is of the latest record inserted in the table, I am facing real problem in this date check only

Comment: Can you please in this regard, I have been trying it since past week and could not find the solution of it

Comment: OK, I've rewritten the query to simplify it a bit and fix the issue you were having.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I prepared the query but this date match put me in trouble for days. I think its time to improve the SQL knowledge now. Thanks again.